# Running Node Inspector on Amazon AWS

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I am trying to run node-inspector on amazon AWS. Through a series of different answers on the web and many hours later I have followed these steps:

1. npm install -g node-inspector
2. ran "node-inspector" from the aws server

   **Got Back:**
        Node Inspector v0.12.5
        Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.
3. from my computer ran " ssh -i mypemkey.pem -L username@amazonhost
4. ran node --debug myapp from the server

   **Got Back:**
      Debugger Listening on port 5858
5. The url I expected to work did not but i finally got this
             127.0.0.1:5858/?ws=127.0.0.1:5858&port5858

   To return This

   **Type:Connect

   v8-Version:3.28.71.19

   Protocol-Version: 1

   Embedding-Host: node v0.12.7

   Content-Length: 0**

I think I am close. I do not understand how the debugger works exactly. What am I missing here?

Thank You for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the order of operations and the wrong ssh information
Step by Step to get node-inspector working on amazon aws  and probably most servers.
nodejs v0.12.7
node-inspector v.0.12.5

1.(on the server) - npm install -g node-inspector --save
2.(from my local command window) - ssh -i [YourPemKey.pem] -L    8080:127.0.0.1:8080 username@amazonDNS
3.(on the server) - node-inspector
    3. Results in: Node Inspector v0.12.5
             Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858
4. (on the server in a separate console) node --debug myApp.js

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858